# Create a list, t, that saves only the athlete’s name if it contains “t”. If it does not contain the letter “t”, save the athlete name into list other

Tags: python

```
athletes = [['Phelps', 'Lochte', 'Schooling', 'Ledecky', 'Franklin'], ['Felix', 'Bolt', 'Gardner', 'Eaton'], ['Biles', 'Douglas', 'Hamm', 'Raisman', 'Mikulak', 'Dalton']]

t = [] 
other = []

for lst in athletes:
    for lst2 in athletes:
        if 't' in lst2:
            t.append(lst2)
        else:
            other.append(lst2)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The inner for loop I think should be `for lst2 in lst`

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in [item for sublist in athletes for item in sublist]:
    t.append(x) if 't' in x else other.append(x)
```

Output:

```
t:  ['Lochte', 'Bolt', 'Eaton', 'Dalton']
other:  ['Phelps', 'Schooling', 'Ledecky', 'Franklin', 'Felix', 'Gardner', 'Biles', 'Douglas', 'Hamm', 'Raisman', 'Mikulak']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `partition` recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
from itertools import chain, tee, filterfalse

def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

athletes = [['Phelps', 'Lochte', 'Schooling', 'Ledecky', 'Franklin'], ['Felix', 'Bolt', 'Gardner', 'Eaton'], ['Biles', 'Douglas', 'Hamm', 'Raisman', 'Mikulak', 'Dalton']]
flat_athletes = chain.from_iterable(athletes)

without_t, with_t = partition(lambda ath: "t" in ath, flat_athletes)
```

`without_t` and `with_t` with be iterators.  If you want to make them lists just do `without_t = list(witout_t)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# make a "flat" list of names
flat_list = sum(athletes, [])


# use list comprehensions
t = [x for x in flat_list if "t" in x]
other = [x for x in flat_list if "t" not in x]
```

Comment: Why would you iterate the whole list twice?

Comment: I think this is more readable than using a for loop, and this isn't going to take much time either way

Comment: It takes ~double the time. And it doesn't explain anything that was wrong with the original approach